# Count number of tabs open in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, count, tabs

How do I count number of tabs are being opened in Browser by using Python Selenium?

Comment: try this link, try the solution mentioned there http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/9553/counting-the-number-of-browser-windows-opened-by-selenium

Answer (score 16):

> How do I count number of tabs are being opened in Browser by using Python Selenium?

Since provided [link answer](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/9553/counting-the-number-of-browser-windows-opened-by-selenium) doesn't have any answer in python, you can get the count number of tabs opened in browser using [`WebDriver#window_handles`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.window_handles) as below :-

```
len(driver.window_handles)
```

Answer (score 4):

For getting the Number of Opened tabs You can use the code below-

The below code will return length as "1" if single tab is opened or "2" if two tabs are opened.

```
len(driver.window_handles)
```

Further If you want to Close all the extra opened tabs and want to keep only the 1st tab opened then try the below Code-

```
driver_len = len(driver.window_handles) #fetching the Number of Opened tabs
print("Length of Driver = ", driver_len)
if driver_len > 1: # Will execute if more than 1 tabs found.
    for i in range(driver_len - 1, 0, -1):
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[i]) #will close the last tab first.
        driver.close()
        print("Closed Tab No. ", i)
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0]) # Switching the driver focus to First tab.
else:
    print("Found only Single tab.")
```